# PLSS Shapefile for Adams county CO

Tags: shapefile, data, united-states, plss, township-range-section

Where can I find a simple TOWNSHIP/RANGE, SECTION, QUARTER SECTION shapefile for Adams County Colorado?

Comment: If this is open data then your question may be better researched/asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Goto navigator.blm.gov  . This has the PLSS data for many of the States in US

https://navigator.blm.gov/data?keyword=PLSS&fs_publicRegion=Colorado

[image: Click to see Screen Shot how to find it]

Comment: "BLM Colorado PLSS Intersected" is the data layer with quarter quarter-sections, lots, tracts, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov](https://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/).

[image]

> The Geospatial Data Gateway (GDG) provides access to a map library of over 100 high resolution vector and raster layers in the Geospatial Data Warehouse. It is the One Stop Source for environmental and natural resources data, at any time, from anywhere, to anyone. It allows you to choose your area of interest, browse and select data, customize the format, then review and download.

Also, you can try an alternative the direct download as well - [Public Land Survey System of the United States - Direct Download](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/public-land-survey-system-of-the-united-states-direct-download)